# Find file names containing value stored in a string variable or object and move that file

Tags: powershell, filenames, string-comparison

I have a folder containing a large list of hofixes. Each hotfix filename contains the KB number such as KB2993958 similar to Windows8.1-KB2957189-x64.msu

I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue caused by the installation of a particular hotfix. I have narrowed the selection down to about 50 possible hotfixes, far less than how many are contained in the master folder.
I want to install 10 hotfixes at a time to try and isolate the issue.

I have the list of 50 hotfixes I need to install either in a get-hotfix object or probably converted to a string in a variable.

So I want to compare the Kb numbers listed in my object / variable against the file names in the master folder and if the file name contains any of the KB number stored in my variable then move this file into a folder, ready for installation.

Seems simple, but I can't work it out.

Comment: Please post your attempts so far and a sample of the data you're working with. See [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

Use `Get-ChildItem` with a filter that contains the KB ID, and pipe it to `Move-Item`.

```
$s = "KB2957189"
$HfPath = "c:\temp\"
$MoveToPath = "c:\temp\temp1\"

get-childitem -path $HfPath -Filter "*$s*" | Move-Item -Destination $MoveToPath
```

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers (or at least add inline comments)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen  Aren't there some situations where a code-only answer is the best answer, e.g. when the question is very clear?